# Weird data from Landsat 8 in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Many time when I try to retrieve statistics from images in GEE, I get some images appears "twice" according to their dates as you can see in this Excel table (I added their order):
[image]

In the past I have realized that this phenomena occurs when the different tiles of Sentinel overlap, and then I get one "big" raster that is full size, and then a small raster (usualy it waas the second one between the two rasters).

However, today when it happened and I checked the images, for example 0 and 1, I got two different full images:

Image 0:

[image]

Image 1:

[image]

(I displayed each one of them alone so that how they look)

How can I avoid those two images on the same date? I have been told that maybe mosaic() can help but I'm not sure how.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat 8 SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image input Landsat 8 SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloudmasked Landsat 8 image
 */
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2013-04-30', '2019-10-16')
                  .select('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','pixel_qa')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskL8sr);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

//clip the dataset according to the geometry
var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
});


Map.centerObject(geometry,15);
//Map.addLayer(clippedCol.median(), visParams);

// Get the number of images.
var count = dataset.size();
print('Count: ',count);
//print(clippedCol);
print(dataset,'dataset');

//function to calculate NDVI in LANDSAT8
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4'])
  .rename('NDVI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(NDVI);

};

//NDWI to the clipped image collection
var withNDVI = clippedCol.map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');

var NDVIcolor = {
  min: -1,
  max:1,
  palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'],
};

var listOfImages =(withNDVI.toList(withNDVI.size()));
var randomImage=ee.Image(listOfImages.get(4));
var randomImage1=ee.Image(listOfImages.get(5));
var randomImage2=ee.Image(listOfImages.get(2));
var randomImage3=ee.Image(listOfImages.get(3));
Map.addLayer(randomImage,NDVIcolor,'Random_Image_tes0t');
Map.addLayer(randomImage1,NDVIcolor,'Random_Image_test1');
Map.addLayer(randomImage2,NDVIcolor,'Random_Image_test2');
Map.addLayer(randomImage2,NDVIcolor,'Random_Image_test3');
print(randomImage,randomImage1,randomImage2,randomImage3);

print(ui.Chart.image.series(withNDVI, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));
print(ui.Chart.image.series(withNDVI, geometry, ee.Reducer.max(), 30));
print(ui.Chart.image.series(withNDVI, geometry, ee.Reducer.min(), 30));
```

Comment: Your geometry is clearly overlapping two different Sentinel tiles, so you get two different summary statistics for each date. One way to see that is to export each image ID along with your dates and indices. If you only want one value over your region, you will need to mosaic them somehow. Check this: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_composite_mosaic

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I wrote "Sentinel" tiles when you're using LS8, but the rest of the comment applies.

Comment: Could you share the definition of your `geometry` variable, so that others can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Tyler, when you say ddefinition. do you mean if I can upload the shapefile or you just wanted to know what is it -it is a polygon-